# DOMPDF is working fine in server, but it gives http error 503 in server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, dompdf

I am facing with an error in laravel. I am using laravel 5.8. I am using dompdf to generate pdf from blade. It is working fine in localhost but it is giving an error in server.
503 Service Unavailable

Answer (score 0):

Composer offers the ability to indicate Php extensions as dependencies, not just packages. It's not capable of installing those, but it does give it a chance to scream loudly if your server environment doesn't support your app. I'd be willing to bet if you added `ext-dom` to it and ran `composer install` it would fail. Some IDEs will even prompt you to add things like that when needed.

All that to say, make sure the [php xml extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.installation.php) is installed. Also check your error log in `storage/logs`.